# What is a cluster IP?

Tags: cluster, web-hosting, windows-cluster

I am in process or configuring remote web host service and I have option of configuring should I use cluster IP.

Could some please explain what a cluster IP is and what are the benefits of using cluster IP?

Just to be clear, I am not configuring a server, I am configuring an order to setup server.

Answer (score 2):

A cluster IP is the virtual IP that represents your clustered service. Typically this is the IP assigned to your clustered service on your load balancer.

Comment: since i have nevered ecountered it, my question may sound stupid. does cluster service implies multiple web-servers in the same network?

Comment: @John: Google is your friend.

Comment: @Iain haha. but sometimes you need to get basic info to start asking questions. even to google...

Comment: You should consider asking your manager for training.

Comment: @John: Perhaps you shouldn't be trying to do something you don't know how to do ...

Comment: @John I understand what you're asking, but there are dozens of technologies that use clustering, all with different implementations, and each have *books* written on them. Are you using Windows Failover Clustering? Netscalars? F5-Big IPs? NLB? HAProxy? There are seriously dozens of ways you can create a "cluster" and all work differently. You're asking someone to distill years of experience into an answer and you haven't said for what tech. It's crazy. You need to understand what you're doing and what technology you're using for it before you can ask a reasonable question.